# Движок для браузера на vb.net

Tags: vb.net, движок

Есть ли браузерный движок типо Presto для vb.net
Кроме WebKit

Comment: **Presto** это движок от **Opera** , не найдете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть **chromium**

[Chrome to VB.Net](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-discuss/l7xw1maFjSE)